# Adding an optional language param to every route in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

As to support bookmarking I want to have unique URLs for each language on my AngularJs based SPA. Ideally I'd like the URLs to looks like this:

```
example.com/#/:langParam
example.com/#/:langParam/home
example.com/#/:langParam/home/news
```

But whenever the language is the default for the deploy (this will usually be en) I would like for :langParam to be completely optional. Is something like the above possible or should I just add the language to the end of the URLs like so:

```
example.com/#/:langParam
example.com/#/home/:langParam
example.com/#/home/news/:langParam
```

Is there a way to automatically apply this to all routes or would I need to add this to each route? Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is going to be a copy/paste job, but would be interested in seeing if there's a better answer